# Jackson Polymorphism Deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

I have the following 4 classes (ignoring constructors, getters, setters):

```
class Animals {
    List<Animal> animals;
}

abstract class Animal {
    String name;
    abstract void sound();
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    void sound() { println("meow"); }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    void sound() { println("woof"); }
}
```

I have a json file containing animals information that looks something like:

```
{
  "animals": [
    {
      "type": "Cat",
      "name": "Foo"
    },
    {
      "type": "Dog",
      "name": "Bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I'd like to deserialize them into their respective classes. From what I've seen online, most tutorials like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance) and [this](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/jackson-json-type-info-annotation.html) have Jackson serialize the objects first (so that the JSON objects contain special attributes like `"@class":"com.logicbig.example.Rectangle"` that helps with deserialization. But the JSON files I'm expecting won't be serialized by Jackson. In that case, how should I go about using `type` in each object to identify what subclass to deserialize this `Animal` in?

Comment: Look at "2.2. Per-Class Annotations" from your first link. `@JsonSubTypes` is your way to go here (`@JsonTypeInfo` is not needed). Just link your two animal subclasses with the corresponding types (like in the snippet in the link).

Comment: @Tom thanks! Followup: my JSON file structure is actually a recursive one, it resembles more of a binary expression (with AND and OR operators), would Jackson be able to handle recursive structures?

Comment: Since this is a Q&A-site there are two cool things you can do: write an answer under this question explaining how you solved your problem, so future readers can learn from it. And then create a new question post with your new question (but check if this question has been asked by someone else already, first).

Comment: @ddolce, could you show your `JSON` payload with recursive structure? You should be able to apply solution proposed in first link you have read, section `2.2. Per-Class Annotations`. In case no, please let us know.